# Segmenting between data sent with analytics.js and Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics

I have a single site with analytics.js loaded on it. If JS is disabled (usually if the visitor is a bot or scraper), I have a mechanism to fall back to using server-side Measurement Protocol calls so that the data is still recorded.

Is there a way I can segment the results to show only the data recorded with analytics.js? Would using appId creatively (`ga('set', 'appId', 'analytics.js');`) or a custom variable when recording the data be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you manipulate the `Data Source` field in your measurement protocol hits.

**First**, when sending measurement protocol hits, set the `ds` field to `server-side` (or a similar name of your choosing).

**Then**, in Google Analytics you can create a segment with the following conditions:

- Dimension: `Data Source`
- Operator: `exactly matches`
- Value: `server-side` (or whatever value you are sending via the `ds` field)